# Active Directory field mapping

Tags: active-directory

The 'company' and 'department' fields in an AD user's profile, are they mapped in any way? Must a department belong to a company? Or are they just text fields with no rules..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just regular string text fields - they are no relations or checks or anything behind those - just put whatever you like into those.